# Scale an image to fit when replacing an image

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to implement a behaviour by which I can add an initial image to a canvas (placeholder) and then subsequently I can then choose a different image to replace that image - that new image should then scale itself to "fit" within the bounds of the old image. For example if I choose a portrait image as the "placeholder" and then choose a landscape image to replace it, Id expect the landscape image to first scale its width and maintain aspect ratio, and then vertically align itself within the boundaries of the placeholder dimensions.

Here is a jsfiddle of what I have working so far: https://jsfiddle.net/cgallagher/co8dg527/1/

and here is the code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('stage');
var cw = canvas.getWidth()
var ch = canvas.getHeight()
var _currentImage;

function setProductImage(url){
    var oldWidth; 
    var oldHeight;
    var oldLeft;
    var oldTop;

    fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(img) {
      if (_currentImage) {
        oldWidth = _currentImage.getScaledWidth()
        oldHeight = _currentImage.getScaledHeight()
        oldLeft = _currentImage.left
        oldTop = _currentImage.top  
        canvas.remove(_currentImage);  
      }

      _currentImage = img;

      img.set({ 'left': oldLeft || 0 })
      img.set({ 'top': oldTop || 0 })

      if (oldHeight && oldHeight > img.getScaledHeight()){
        img.scaleToWidth(oldWidth);
        img.set({'height': oldHeight })
      } else if (oldWidth > img.getScaledWidth()){
        img.scaleToHeight(oldHeight);
        img.set({'width': oldWidth })
      }

      img.selectable = true
      canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img);
    });
  }

  function addImage(url){
    setProductImage(url)
    canvas.renderAll()
  }
```

You can see that the image does scale the way I'd like but it doesn't then align itself.

I'm toying with the idea of dropping a bounding box around the image too and possibly trying to align and scale within that but I'm not sure this is even possible with fabric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I had done.
When you run `scaleToWidth` and `scaleToHeight` the `scaleX` and`scaleY` is changing and you need to adjust the `oldHeight` and `oldWidth` to the new `img.scaleX`/`img.scalaY`
I also rewrite `_renderFill` method from `fabric.Image.prototype` to create that offset effect.
Check here:https://jsfiddle.net/mariusturcu93/co8dg527/37/

**Code**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Fabric kicking</title>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.0/fabric.js"></script>
    <style>
      #stage {
        border: solid 1px #333;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="addImage('https://s.hs-data.com/bilder/spieler/gross/208995.jpg')">Add image</button>
    <button onclick="addImage('https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/67/590x/Mateusz-Klich-883903.jpg')">add another image</button>
    <canvas id="stage" width="600" height="600"></canvas>

    <script>

    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('stage');
    var cw = canvas.getWidth()
    var ch = canvas.getHeight()
    var _currentImage;

    function setProductImage(url){
        var oldWidth; 
        var oldHeight;
        var oldLeft;
        var oldTop;

        fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(img) {
          if (_currentImage) {
            oldWidth = _currentImage.getScaledWidth()
            oldHeight = _currentImage.getScaledHeight()
            oldLeft = _currentImage.left
            oldTop = _currentImage.top  
            canvas.remove(_currentImage);  
          }

          _currentImage = img;

          img.set({ 'left': oldLeft || 0 })
          img.set({ 'top': oldTop || 0 })

          if (oldHeight && oldHeight > img.getScaledHeight()){

            img.scaleToWidth(oldWidth);
            img.set({'height': oldHeight/img.scaleX})
          } else if (oldWidth > img.getScaledWidth()){

            img.scaleToHeight(oldHeight);
            img.set({'width': oldWidth/img.scaleY })
          }

          img.selectable = true
          canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img);
        });
      }

      function addImage(url){
        setProductImage(url)
        canvas.renderAll()
      }      
    </script>
    <img src="https://s.hs-data.com/bilder/spieler/gross/208995.jpg" />
    <img src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/67/590x/Mateusz-Klich-883903.jpg" />
  </body>
</html>
```

`fabric.Image.prototype._renderFill` **rewrite**

```
fabric.Image.prototype._renderFill= (function(renderFill){
    return function(ctx) {

      var w = this.width, h = this.height, sW = w * this._filterScalingX, sH = h * this._filterScalingY,
          x = -w / 2, y = -h / 2, elementToDraw = this._element;

          y = y  + Math.abs((this._element.height-h)/2);
          x = x  + Math.abs((this._element.width-w)/2);
      elementToDraw && ctx.drawImage(elementToDraw,
        this.cropX * this._filterScalingX,
        this.cropY * this._filterScalingY,
        sW,
        sH,
        x, y, w, h);
    }
})()
```

Comment: as i know, its not always acceptable to override private methods.

Comment: What cgallagher needs fabricjs not support (I mean that offset in the block). I need to change that function. If @cgallagher will not use toSVG method I think will not create any problem

Comment: I'm not saying is the only solution. This is just what was cross my mind first time

Comment: Your approach is an interesting one @MariusTurcu . I came up with something myself in the mean time that seems to actually work.

https://jsfiddle.net/cgallagher/hLor5ewb/

The code is rough for the time being but I create a placeholder box with the dimensions of the first image added and then place the first image in a group with that. Any images added after this are then scaled to width / height depending on their dimensions. I'm not sure if I'm catching edge cases just yet though.